# How to delete unwanted informations from javadoc

Tags: javadoc

I've just created a Javadoc documentation of my Java Project, but I've pointed out that there are too many informations: I just want public interface (id est Constructors and Public Methods of all my class) to be written.
Instead I see information like "Methods inherited from class javax.swing.JFrame" and other that I definitely don't want. 
It's possible with javadoc to documentate only public interface?
I thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the level of documentation you want to generate with the command line options passed when you execute the Javadoc tool. The option you want is `-public`.

You can read more about that in [the reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#javadocoptions).

Comment: I've yet tried to set only "public", but I see even all of these informations I don't want. By the way, I thank you for your hint

Comment: By default you get protected and public members in the docs you generate. I thought you wanted only the public members. So you want public members, but not those inherited from other classes, is that it?

Comment: yeah you're right. I just to want for all of my classes public methods and constructors.. I think that a documentation like this is simpler to be read and give an overall view of the project